# Do you know of any Java bytecode interpreters?

Tags: java, interpreter, bytecode

i am looking for a Java interpreter not a JVM (no JIT)

till now i have checked

- llvm vmkit
- gij (from gcj)
- jikesrvm (JVM)
- Kaffe (JVM)

However, as i only need an interpreter i would prefer to find something simpler and smaller (in LOCs) preferably written in C/C++

Comment: I'm pretty sure there are JVM options to turn off JITting.  What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: Trying to run Java on an embedded system and at this moment i just need something small that works :) (i don't really need the whole Java's functionality)

Comment: Write your own.  It's not that complicated.  (Well, not the interpreter, that is.  All the supporting stuff is what's complicated.)

Comment: That's what i am trying to avoid ;) (laziness)
Furthermore that's another advantage of open-source re-usability.

Comment: Many years ago, Dallas Semiconductor released an iButton which included a Java interpreter.  I think it had a total of 6K of user-accessible RAM, into which bytecode and variables had to fit.  I think the idea was to use it as a security token.  I think the product was a flop, since it wasn't quite powerful enough to do anything really interesting, but its existence would suggest that a Java interpreter can run on a very limited platform.

Comment: I have also found squawk (squawk.java.net)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JamVM, if you don't mind the simple code-copying JIT in the last version. "Code-copying" probably means a simple way avoiding switch statement.

See http://jamvm.sourceforge.net/

Comment: Thanks a lot that's what I am checking now :), but forgot to come back and mention it.